# Firebase query for existence of keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure (of events) and want to query for all events a particular user (`user1`) is part of.

```
{
    "events":{
        "event1":{
            "users":{
                "user1":true,
                "user2":true
            }
        },
        "event2":{
            "users":{
                "user1":true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following query allows me to get all events `user1` is part of but in a ways that does not allow me to create DB indexes.

`starRef.child("events").orderByChild("users/user1").start(true).end(true)`

I'm looking for a way that allows me to (at best) query for the existence of a key. For example `starRef.child("events").orderByChild("users").hasKey("user1")`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, i recomand you change your database structure a little bit, by adding a new node named `events` within each user. Your new node should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   --- users
     --- user1
       --- events
         --- event1: true
         --- event2: true
```

To query for all events that corespond to a particular user, just add a listener to `"Firebase-root/users/user1/events"` and get all the events from which that user belongs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah I know that I have this option. But I would prefer a way that allows me to not fan out (duplicate) data. But thx for this info.

Comment: This is the best option for solving your problem. Unfortunately, with your actual database structure you cannot achieve this. Pelase note, that [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). See this video and you'll understand better. As a conclusion, duplicating data is for simplify and reduce query and this what you need. ;)

Comment: From my perspective I'm already able to do the query I want to do. I was only hoping to do it with an index. But as it is not a very common query and it runs on a cloud functions I'm not going to denormalize until all related queries of this project are fixed.

Comment: Remember, using Denormalization (duplicating data) it's not bad practive when it comes to Firebase. Denormalization is a very common practice that helps you reduce your queries.

Comment: I do know that and I use it extensively. But if I can avoid it, I do so. Particularly, for cloud functions, as one function might call the other one, when updating information at 2 places.